# Convert Lead activity issue in JB

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, lead-conversion

[Journey Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFjrd.jpg)Our MC org is integrated with a Sales Cloud org. I have attached Journey screenshots with client name blanked out. I have been trying all sorts of configuration options on the "Convert Lead activity" but it keeps failing. I have synchronized DE's lead, contact, account, campaign and individual email result setup. If you have any other questions or need details please let me know. Can someone help me find out why the convert lead activity keeps failing? The welcome email message goes out as expected. We have verified on the sales cloud that the lead conversion process is working as expected. only one common record type on lead, contact and accountin sales cloud. diasabled the "Require Validation for Converted Leads" checkbox on sales cloud. Need help urgently? [image: Covert Lead activity history][image: Convert Lead activity JB summary][image: Journey Screenshot]

Comment: I have the same problem. But I think this is due to the presence of the same email address in the current Contact Object.